# Unable to use TabLayout

Tags: android, xml, tabs

I have made TabLayout in XML file of for an android application. Like that

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tabs">

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Now I am trying to access TabLayout in java file, but I am unable to do so.Please see attached snapshot and help me that where I am mistaking.Please help me.

[image: Snapshot from code file]

Comment: Have you included support design library in build.gradle ?

Comment: can you add your dependencies?

Comment: yeah i have added following dependence in gradle file :                                            compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

Comment: But still it is unable to resolve TabLayout

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project

Comment: I implemented your code, there is no problem. what `R` did you import?

Comment: What is the support version your using?  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'   try to clean and build

Comment: i think you didnt added the design dependency in your build file , i poseted the answer below , follow that it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use TabLayout The first thing you need to do is include the Design Support Library in the dependencies of the app’s **build.gradle** file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' 
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

In the activity layout (activity_tab_layout.xml) we place a TabLayout widget and a ViewPager:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="4dip"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="net.voidynullness.android.tabitytabs.TabLayoutActivity">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

now inside respective activity say **TabLayoutActivity.java** add this below code

```
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
   import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


    public class TabLayoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       TabLayout tabs ;
       ViewPager pager;
       TabsPagerAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_layout);

       tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
       pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
       adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
       pager.setAdapter(adapter);
       tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);
  }
}
```

and run it will work for you

Comment: Thanks for worthy answer.